# .py with .bat file won't run

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

So to start off programming as a whole, some friends recommended learning python first before going into something else. I started reading Automate the Boring Stuff with Python by Al Sweigart and I find it a neat thing for beginners.

Anywho, I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to run a certain project (named pw.py, which is an insecure password copier) from the Run window. I did everything that needs to be done: created a .bat file; added the extension to the environment; and, of course, installed python correctly. However, when I try to run it, the cmd screen shows for a split second then goes off without copying anything. I tried to define different variables whose values are `input()` in different lines to detect where the problem is going off with no success - it kept doing the same thing. I even tried to remove `sys.exit()` because I thought it was causing an issue.
Can anyone help with this?

The code I'm trying to run:

```
#! python3

#pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

passwords = {'email':'ffd458fds8eth369h',
             'blog':'uibpvnt843kjlg8u65',
             'luggage': '12345'}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] #first command line arg is the account name

if account in passwords:
    pyperclip.copy(passwords[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + 'copied to clipboard.')


else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

The batch file contains:

```
@py.exe C:\path\pw.py %*  
@pause
```

I also tried another one:

```
@echo off  
python c:\path\pw.py %*  
pause
```

I've inserted these into the run window (using all different kinds of parentheses):

```
pw.py <email>
C:\path\pw.py <email>  
C:\windows\py.exe c:\path\pw.py <email> #(I don't know if this one is correct but I tried it anyway)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and it seems to work just fine expect:

> The batch file contains: @py.exe C:\path\pw.py %* @pause

**try specifying your interpreter full path**

for example:

```
@"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\someuser\PycharmProjects\test\pw.py" %*
```

Comment: It didn't work - still won't copy. But it's good to know that there's nothing wrong with the code (i.e I did everything right). May I ask what you're typing into the run window? I'm afraid I might be passing a wrong argument or something.

Comment: I am just using the bat file like you, i also took the import you did and put it in the top of the script... try it too

Comment: wow. putting the import on the top actually worked. That's odd. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, have a great day!